# Python. Sum values with a step inside list

Tags: python

I'm newbie in Python, so my question is a trivial one.

Suppose i have a list of data imported from excel:

`daily = pd.read_excel (r'path to excel')`
`daily = daily.to_numpy()`

"daily" contains daily observations of a certain variable.

my goal is to sum all observations with a step of 7 (one week) and store the results in a new variable "week".
"daily" contains 300+ entries so "week" will have 300+//7 = 42+ entries.

I've done something like this:
`week1 = sum(daily[0:7])`
`week2 = sum(daily[7:14])`
`week3 = sum(daily[14:21])`
`week4 = sum(daily[21:28])` and so on...

`week = (week1, week2, week3, ...)`
How can i write this in a more clever way with for/if statements?
Thank you

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. _How can i write this in a more clever way with for/if statements?_ Is there a specific issue? Are you familiar with using loops and `if` statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One concise way of doing this would be using [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). Based on your question, though, I would recommend familiarizing yourself with the usage of loops in general.

```
week = [numpy.sum(daily[x:numpy.min(len(daily),x+7)]) for x in range(0, len(daily), 7)]
```

This produces a list where each element is the sum of the elements of `daily` from index `x` to `min(x+7, len(daily))` (so that we don't exceed the boundaries of daily). [`range(start, stop, step)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) produces an iterable from 0 to the length of daily, stepping by 7 each time.

Comment: Helpfull insights. i've done just a little modification for your code (droping x*7)  week = [sum(data[x:min(len(data),x+7)]) for x in range(0, len(data), 7)]